# Why Linux java -version by ssh give different result?

Tags: java, linux, ssh, centos, version

So my problem is why when I execute "java -version" command as root in my cent os it gives me "java runtime 1.7". But when I use ssh to ssh the same root user and execute "java -version", I got "java JDK 1.6" and this problem causing my deploy activity not working. So anyone know, why I got different result when use ssh command and not.

Thanks all...

Answer (score 3):

The problem is due to setting of $PATH being different in the two contexts.

Run `echo $PATH` and `which java` in both contexts and compare the results.

Irrespective of why the $PATH settings are different, one solution is to use the absolute pathname for the `java` binary that you want.

---

It is also worth noting that both Java 6 and Java 7 are passed EOL, and you should really be upgrading your applications to use Java 8.  Especially if you are using Java to run network-exposed services ... or (>>shudder<<) in a web browser.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are your root login has a different `PATH` environment variable setting than your `ssh` login shell.

`which java` will probably (depending which shells you're using) tell you which `java` binary is first in your `PATH`.

Comment: Thanks mark, now I'm understand, but how can I setting my linux to get ssh environment variable same with root environment variables. Because, the one that make me confused is that I ssh the root user too.

Comment: It depends how you are becoming `root`: normal local login, `su root`, or `su - root`. Each will run different shell initialization scripts.